# detecting user timezones in model

Tags: django

I need to get user timezones in order to convert a naive datetime to local time. However it's for an admin view, so it looks like I'm pretty much stuck fitting this into the model. request.session.get('django_timezone') is not available in the model, so how can you detect the timezone?

Comment: You can not. The user time zone is only available via frontend scripting.

Comment: `django_timezone` is available only in django 1.4 and up.. what version are you running?, also `request.session` properties, are not available in models.

Answer (score 2):

You should store the user's timezone on their profile, then access it with:

```
tz = some_user.get_profile().timezone
```

For more about Django user profiles, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users